# When to use python interpreter vs shell

Tags: python, shell, interpreter

I have a very basic question: If we want to run a script called script.py, we go to shell and type "python script.py". However, if we want to check, for example, if Django is installed or not, we first go into Python interpreter by typing "python" in the shell, and while we get the >>> then we type import Django. What is the conceptual difference? For example, in the second case, why directly running "python import Django" in the shell does not work?

Comment: One runs Python code and the other executes programs and shell commands.

Answer (score 2):

`python import Django` tries to run a Python script named `import` with an argument `Django`.

`python -c 'import Django'` would attempt to execute the Python statement `import Django` as if you had typed it from the Python interpreter directly.

Answer (score 0):

`python` launch interpreter. You can easly test script on it, and after create a file *.py that you can use on CRON (for ex)

When you type `python` and `import Django` it do

1. Open Python interpreter
2. Import Django library on it (to use it)

If an error raise, it seems than Django wasn't installed on computer